# apache2.4.2+resin-3.1.9

Tags: apache2, resin

for creating mod_caucho.so, i run resin configure, when i execute make command, some errors:

```
/home/xsmapp/temp/resin-3.1.9/>make
(cd modules/c/src; make)
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/xsmapp/temp/resin-3.1.9/modules/c/src'
for dir in common apache2 resin resinssl resin_os; do (cd $dir; make); done
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/xsmapp/temp/resin-3.1.9/modules/c/src/common'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/xsmapp/temp/resin-3.1.9/modules/c/src/common'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/xsmapp/temp/resin-3.1.9/modules/c/src/apache2'
EGREP="/bin/grep -E" /home/xsmapp/temp/resin-3.1.9/libtool --silent --tag=CXX --mode=compile gcc -o mod_caucho.lo -c -I/home/xsmapp/appserver/apache-2.4.2/include  -I/home/xsmapp/appserver/apr/include/apr-1  -DRESIN_HOME=\"/home/xsmapp/temp/resin-3.1.9\" -I../common -g -O2 -DPOLL -DEPOLL -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -DHAS_SOCK_TIMEOUT -DHAS_JVMTI -DHAS_JVMDI   -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE  -g -O2 -pthread mod_caucho.c
***mod_caucho.c: In function `write_env':
mod_caucho.c:588: error: structure has no member named `remote_ip'
mod_caucho.c:590: error: structure has no member named `remote_ip'
mod_caucho.c:591: error: structure has no member named `remote_addr'***
mod_caucho.c: In function `caucho_request':
mod_caucho.c:896: error: structure has no member named `remote_ip'
make[2]: *** [mod_caucho.lo] 错误 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/xsmapp/temp/resin-3.1.9/modules/c/src/apache2'
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you please reformat your code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a version problem. 
Resin 3.1.* are suitable for Apache2.2.*, but not guarantee to the newest Apache2.4.*

I used Apache 2.2.22 + Resin3.1.8, and is OK.

Answer (score 0):

thanks hongtium. I have to find a way to compile successfully.

`vi resin-3.1.9\modules\c\src\apache2\mod_caucho.c`

at line 588
/*

```
  if (c->remote_host)
    cse_write_string(s, CSE_REMOTE_HOST, c->remote_host);
  else
    cse_write_string(s, CSE_REMOTE_HOST, c->remote_ip);

  cse_write_string(s, CSE_REMOTE_ADDR, c->remote_ip);
  sprintf(buf, "%u", ntohs(c->remote_addr->port));
```

*/

at line 856
`//ip = r->connection->remote_ip;`

then, you can `create mod_caucho.so`